Women didn’t yet have the vote (=at that time)

(1) Women didn’t yet have the vote (=at that time). (Longman)
(2) Women haven't yet had the vote.

Based on what I learned in school, only (2) is correct.
Why is (1) correct? Is that because "have" is a stative verb?

won or had the right to vote is more idiomatic. Women didn't yet climb moutains, play tennis, shoot guns, tear down societal restrictions on them. etc. Not because of a stative verb.

"to have the vote" can mean "to be lawfully able to vote" (i.e. to have the right to vote) or to "to put something up on a ballot for voting, so that people can vote".  Let's end the debate and have the vote on this measure.  So before women had the lawful ability to vote, they did not have the vote (i.e. the right to vote).   "Has the town council voted on the dog park measure? --No, they have not yet had the vote."

(2) is  not correct, either factually or grammatically (unless there is a country where women are still not allowed to vote). It should be Women do not yet have the vote or haven't yet been given the [right to] vote.

#2 is syntactically valid, but would require an unusual context to be idiomatic. It really requires a very firmly established "narrative reference time", such as "Imagine you have invented a time machine, and the first time you use it, you are transported back to the 19h century..." Personally, I don't think ...you have been transported back... establishes the "present in the past" firmly enough to justify format #2

@Lambie I'm not sure whether Did Susan come back yet? is possible in British English.

In American English, possibly also in British English, one can say informally that "Women didn't have the vote in the 19th century" with the meaning "Did not have the right to vote".

Women didn't have the vote yet.
Women did not yet have the vote.

Since "the vote" is being construed  in that construction as a right, it is something possessed, and when we wish to say that at a certain point in time in the past someone did not possess something yet, we use "did":

They did not [possess | have]  it yet.
They have not [possessed  | had]  it yet. unidiomatic

